# Warp terminal launch through skhd

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, macos

Did anyone get [Warp Terminal][1] to work with [skhd][2]?

I use to use Kitty with

```bash
cmd - return : /Applications/kitty.app/Contents/MacOS/kitty --single-instance -d ~
```

I'm trying to get launch it with:

```bash
cmd - return : /Applications/Warp.app/Contents/MacOS/stable ~
```

```bash
cmd - return : open /Applications/Warp.app/
```

But this dosen't launch the app.
[1]: https://www.warp.dev/
[2]: https://www.google.com/search?q=skhd%20mac&oq=skhd%20mac&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i19.901j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cmd - return : open -na /Applications/Warp.app
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that your answer is rather terse; you may want to add some explanation why _this_ approach will succeed where the OP's attempts failed.